# Finding the bit length of an Integer in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to find the bit-length (i.e., the index of the highest set bit) of an `Integral` type in Haskell - like the corresponding methods in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength()) or [Python](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/bit_length.html).

The best I could come up with is to do a binary search using right shifts, like so:

```
bitLength :: Bits a => a -> Int
bitLength x = fst $ until (\ (lo,hi) -> lo >= hi) bsIter (0, until test (*2) 1)
  where test n = shiftR x n == zeroBits
        bsIter (lo, hi)
          | test mid = (lo, mid)
          | otherwise = (succ mid, hi)
          where mid = (lo + hi) `div` 2
```

But this feels like re-inventing the wheel, and also might be made more efficient for very large `Integer`s by taking advantage of knowledge of the underlying representation.

(Note, the provided [bitSize function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:bitSize) is more about the maximum number of bits in a numeric type, which is not what I need here.)

Comment: Can also be made more efficient on `Int` range through `CLZ`

Comment: Maybe function [integerLog2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-logarithms-1.0.3/docs/src/Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms.html#integerLog2)  ?

Comment: `Integral` or `Integer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start from an Integral type, this should be able to do:

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms

bitLength :: Integral a => a -> Int
bitLength n = integerLog2 (fromIntegral n)
```

Test under ghci:

```
 λ> 
 λ> bitLength 64
6
 λ> 
 λ> bitLength 127
6
 λ> 
 λ> bitLength 1
0
 λ> 
 λ> bitLength 0

*** Exception: Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms.integerLog2: argument must be positive
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Math/NumberTheory/Logarithms.hs:82:19 in integer-logarithms-1.0.3-L1fXvdNnENnEcLpMml0rI7:Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms
 λ>
```

### EDIT:

Regarding your comment, definitely if function `bitLength` is to live up to its name, it must return the *1-based*, not the zero-based index of the highest set bit.

So a suitably corrected version of `bitLength` would be like this:

```
import  Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms  (integerLog2')

bitLength :: Integral a => a -> Int
bitLength n =
    if (n > 0) then (succ . integerLog2' . fromIntegral) $ n
               else  if (n == 0) then 0
                                 else error "bitLength: negative input !"
```

Re-testing under ghci:

```
 λ> 
 λ> bitLength 0
0
 λ> bitLength 1
1
 λ> bitLength 2
2
 λ> bitLength 120
7
 λ> bitLength (-1)
*** Exception: bitLength: negative input !
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at bitLength.hs:25:39 in main:Main
 λ>
```

**Note:** On the other hand, the `Bits` interface (*class*) does not seem to offer an easy way to convert the item at hand into an `Integer`, probably because existing library instances are `Integral` to begin with.

Comment: Great idea, it's just off by one from the typical definition of "bit length". I think we could write instead `bitLength = succ . integerLog2' . fromIntegral`

Comment: @Dan R - Yes you're right. I have updated my answer accordingly.